# How to redirect in same tab in after form submisson inspring mvc controller

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, jquery-ui-tabs

Here,I have created multiple table in single jsp page. Each tabs had a different forms, If i submit  the 2nd tab form it will be move on first tab.I don;t want move on first tab.It will be held on Second Tab.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">

  <li class="active"><a  href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Home</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">About</a</li>
 <li class=""><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Settings</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Contact </a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have any `tabId` ?

Comment: iam using bootstrap 3. In that there is no tab id

Comment: you can active 2nd tab after submitting your form by `$('.nav-tabs a[href="#tab2"]').tab('show');`

Comment: i want to dynamically change the tab active by every form submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically activate your tab by using the method

```
function activaTab(tabId){
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tabId + '"]').tab('show');
};
```

Now call the method and activate your tab like

```
activaTab('tab1');
activaTab('tab2');
activaTab('tab3');
```

Comment: Thanks... But It has some problem It will take some time for loading from tab1 to tab2

Comment: Noted that, all the data reside in same page with different tabId. then how could you find loading time? there is no loading time after clicking the tab, rather it just show the data after clicking the tab.